# Why Am I getting javascript error : "This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."?

Tags: javascript, c#, web-services, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I've a web site where i'm hosting a mysql database, a website and a webapi app (say: https://my-website.com/webapi).
Then I've a  WebGl app hosted on a CDN (says: https://www.mycdn.com/myapp)

After WebGl app is downloaded into user browser, user must login or register. Login check is made from webgl app to https://my-website.com/webapi .

I'm getting this error:

```
The page at .. page name ... was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint http://my-website.com/webapi.  This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I can assure that in my C# Unity code i'm calling my web api via https.

What can be the error ?

Comment: Well the URL is right there in the error message. Perhaps some of your code isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: "I can assure that in my C# Unity code i'm calling my web api via https." Did you check your javascript as well? XMLHttpRequest is a javascript object.

Comment: Maybe it can be a CORS error. If yes , how and where can I set CORS ?

Comment: It doesn't look like a CORS error. It looks like some code on the page is trying to make an XHR to an http URL.